# Conditionally skip argument in terraform module

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of an [EKS module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks). However, the upstream maintainers have made a bunch of breaking changes, that will cause the EKS cluster being maintained to be rebuilt. It's possible to set overrides to prevent the rebuild from happening, but that results in something like this:

```
 module "eks" {
    source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
    version = " v18.31.2"

    # Override default values to maintain backwards compatibility.
    prefix_separator                   = ""
    cluster_security_group_description = "EKS cluster security group."
    cluster_security_group_name        = var.cluster_name
    iam_role_arn                       = local.iam_role_arn
    create_iam_role                    = false

    ...
  }
```

I would prefer to use the default values for any new cluster builds, and only use these overrides for existing EKS clusters. I attempted to use the ternary operator to conditionally set the arguments only if the cluster was migrated from v17, but this just passes in a literal "null", rather than omitting the argument like I expected.

```
 module "eks" {
    source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
    version = " v18.31.2"

    prefix_separator                   = var.v17_migration ? "" : null
    cluster_security_group_description = var.v17_migration ? "EKS cluster security group." : null
    cluster_security_group_name        = var.v17_migration ? var.cluster_name : null
    iam_role_arn                       = var.v17_migration ? local.iam_role_arn : null
    create_iam_role                    = var.v17_migration ? false : null

    ...
  }
```

Is it possible to conditionally pass an argument to a module? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Where are the default values defined? Are they default values of a module or your own external default values?

Comment: @Marcin They're the default values for the upstream module. I could copy paste them from the upstream module here, but surely there must be a better method?

Comment: The is no "better" way. But you can try with `prefix_separator                   = var.v17_migration ? "" : module.eks.prefix_separator`. Instead of `null` use `module.eks.prefix_separator`. You can make similar changes for the other arguments.

Comment: Yes using the `null` type as a value causes different behavior between resource parameters and module parameters. As a fallback option: you may want to consider managing current clusters with the older module version, and new clusters with the new module version. As old clusters are decommissioned and replaced with new clusters, this could be a decent rollout backup option.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Unfortunately, there's functionality in the newer versions of the module that we would need on the older clusters as well, so we are forced to use the newer module on the older clusters as well.

Comment: For backward-compatibility with older versions of Terraform, the default behavior for input variables is for assigning `null` to literally assign null as you saw, even though that's not how nulls behave elsewhere. A module author can opt in to better treatment of that by setting `nullable = false` in the variable declaration, but that's not something you can set as the caller of the module... you'd need to fork the module and modify it.

Comment: If the module authors would be willing to support this use-case then you could try submitting a pull request to add `nullable = false` to all of these input variable declarations and then they'll behave the way you wanted, with `null` causing the variable to take on the default value rather than literally `null`.

Comment: @MartinAtkins That's pretty handy actually, I'll see if they'll accept it as an upstream change.